# Calling a js file twice from 2 other js files causes the function to be not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have four JavaScript files as follows:

**API.js**

```
var controller = require('./Controller');

var apifunction = new function(){
controller.a(function(result) {
   console.log("result: " + result)
})}
```

**Controller.js**

```
var bll = require('./BLL.js');

module.exports = 
{
   a: function(callback){
      bll.b(function(result){
        callback(result);
      })
   }

  c: function(callback){
     callback(result);
     }
  }
}
```

**BLL.js**

```
var controller = require('./Controller.js');

module.export = 
{

  b: function(callback){
    controller.c(function(result){
      callback(result);
    })
  }

}
```

So the API function that calls the *a function* in the controller which again calls the *b function* in the *BLL*.

In the *BLL* it calls the *c function* in the controller again but then I get an *Error: controller.c is not a function*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing trailing comma (,)? For example a,c are keys in module.exports, so there must be a comma between a & c

Answer (score 0):

Controller.js and BLL.js "require" each other, that's the problem, one will get a empty module(placeholder).

You can refactor it, remove the bidirectional "require", such as pass one module as parameter to the other.

Comment: Tangxinfa thanks for the help but I am not sure how I would pass one module as parameter to the other.  I am just not sure how to implement this in my code

Answer (score 0):

Consider seperating out the function controller.c into a seperate file...E.g. commonC.js

CommonC.js

```
module.exports = 
{
  c: function(callback){
     callback(result);
     }
  }
}
```

Controller.js

```
var bll = require('./BLL.js');

module.exports = 
{
   a: function(callback){
      bll.b(function(result){
        callback(result);
      })
   }
}
```

BLL.js

```
var controller = require('./Controller.js');
var commonC = require('./CommonC.js');

module.export = 
{

  b: function(callback){
    commonC.c(function(result){
      callback(result);
    })
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if refactoring is not an option (you should refactor), you can put the require inside the function so that it executes when the function is invoked.

Controller.js

```
module.exports = 
{
   a: function(callback){
      var bll = require('./BLL.js');
      bll.b(function(result){
        callback(result);
      })
   }

  c: function(callback){
     callback(result);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of functions that i would have to create a separate file for.  Is there an easier way to fix this?

Comment: So I am trying to update it based on how the link does it but everytime i run the function I get controller is not a function.  I am adding a line in bll.js in the b function that states: myController = new controller(this); myController.c();

Comment: so got it to work i added  _ = require('underscore'); and then added _.extends(module.exports, {...});          
Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad i could help :)